# Facing issue with arabic meta tags

Tags: php, seo, meta-tags, arabic-support, meta-title

I am trying to set Arabic titles into meta titles but for some reason most of titles are not working or came in incorrect format.

e.g. [image]

I am using same title which is highlighted as "Correct Title" but due to some reason title tag over on wrong place in page source.

Page encoding is also UTF-8.

Here is code which i am using for display

```
<title>
   <?php echo $arrTags['title']; ?> 
</title>
```

$arrTags['title'] is dynamic string which is arabic texts and also if i try with some static titles like below is also not working

```
<title>
سيارات هيونداي‬ ‫مستعملة للبيع في المملكة العربية السعودية | أبي سيارة
<?php // echo mb_convert_encoding($arrTags['title'], "UTF-8");?>
</title>
```

I had tried many PHP functions also like utf8_encode, mb_convert_encoding those are also not working

Can anybody help me out for this ?

Comment: I think you should write all content between the title tag.

Comment: @irfan title tag content is dynamic and some of those are came into correct format or most of are close at wrong page into page source..

Comment: In this part `<?php echo $arrTags['title']; ?>` search </title> if found then replace by space else no change try it.

Comment: Could you please include a minimal code snippet in the question (as actual text, not image)?